# How to prevent HashMap to store duplicate Object type value and returns the existing value reference?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have below program snippet.

```
public class MapKeyAsAnObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "abc"); // P
        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "xyz");
        Map<Employee, String> map = new HashMap<Employee, String>();
        map.put(e1, "Object1");
        map.put(e2, "Object2");

        System.out.println(map.get(e1)); // A
        System.out.println(map.get(new Employee(1, "abc"))); //B
    }
}

// My pojo class
class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Employee(int id, String arg) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = arg;
    }            
}
```

> In Above program, statement 'A' returns "Value1" which is fine because
>   i pass the same reference to get the value but in statement 'B' which
>   returns null but i want to get "Value1" Because both Employee class in statement 'P' and 'B' having same employee data which i want to prevent to store as well as want to return the reference of e1 in statement 'B' .what should be done to achieve the goal.

Comment: @Boris the spider, My question is a bit different then the existing one when i am asking to prevent the duplicate data insertion while returning the existing one reference.

Comment: Then your question is very unclear - there is no "statement A", "Value1" doesn't appear anywhere in your code, and it's unclear where duplicates could arise.

Comment: Mistakenly removed, Now added.

Comment: Your question is the same - you have not defined **duplicate** or **same** as you have not defined `equals()` and `hashCode()`.